# Adding a settings page to an app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having issues adding a settings page to my app.

I've created a SettingsActivity, SettingsFragment, a actibity_settings.xml layout and a preferences.xml file.

I've placed a button in my activity_main view and added an intent to the MainActivity to call the SettingsActivity.

However placing the button doesn't seem to do anything.

SettingsActivity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    public static void start(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // TODO handle any special logic on change of a preference if you want
    }
}
```

SettingsFragment

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

MainActivity, omitted rest of the methods.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        ...
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(BAR_COLOUR)));
    context = getApplicationContext();

    View createButton = findViewById(R.id.locate_button);
    createButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    latitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_textview);
    latitudeTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.define_location, 0, 0, 0);
    latitudeValueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_value_textview);
    longitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_textview);
    longitudeTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.define_location, 0, 0, 0);
    longitudeValueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_value_textview);
    accuracyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accuracy_textview);
    accuracyTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.info, 0, 0, 0);
    accuracyValueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accuracy_value_textview);
    lastUpdateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_update_view);
    lastUpdateValueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_update_date);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    isPermissionGiven();

}
```

Preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_catOne"
        android:key="pref_key_catOne" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="mockCheckBox"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:title="@string/pref_mockCheckBoxOne"
            android:summary="@string/pref_mockCheckBoxSummary" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="mockCheckBox"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:title="@string/pref_mockCheckBoxTwo"
            android:summary="@string/pref_mockCheckBoxSummary" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_catTwo"
        android:key="pref_key_catTwo" >
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

activity_settings.xml

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    class="org.softshack.SettingsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

main_activity.xml (only the button)

```
<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/accuracy_textview"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton" />
```

Comment: What does happen so far? Can you give us some context?  Is the settings activity even being started in the first place?

Comment: It stays on the same page and doesn't start the settings activity.

Comment: See my updated answer with a full working example of a settings page.

Comment: I'll look at it when I get home in an hour or so, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of your on click pattern but if you want to keep it just use:

```
View settingsButton = findViewById(R.id. settingsButton);
settingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Someone else in my group for this assignment did that part for our learning  assignment.  I'll try this in the onClick method now.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks ! So the way the onClick method has been done in this is wrong  then? How is it meant to be implemented ?

Comment: You would normally set on click for each element separately.  But I would recommend using [ButterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).

Answer (score 0):

Your **SettingsActivity** should extend from **PreferenceActivity**, not Activity:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Clicking the button does nothing and doesn't throw any errors neither.

Comment: You're going to have to add a bit more code for us to look at

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example of all the parts necessary for the settings page.

Create a layout for the activity `activity_settings.xml`:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    class="com.yourorg.yourapp.package.to.SettingsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Update the `class` attr to reflect the path to your `SettingsFragment`.  Simply delete it and start typing and it should auto-complete in android studio.

Create a Settings activity `SettingsActivity.java`:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    public static void start(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // TODO handle any special logic on change of a preference if you want
    }
}
```

Create `SettingsFragment.java`:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Clicking the button does nothing and doesn't throw any errors neither.

Comment: I tried it with your revisions, clicking the button still does nothing. I will update the code in my original question

Comment: Did you declare the activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?  Can you put a breakpoint where `startActivity()` is being called to see if it even gets there?

Comment: You have implemented the on click for the entire activity rather than just the button. Get rid of the `implements OnClickListener` on `MainActivity` and also the overridden onClick member method. In onCreate() of the activity add: `findViewByid(R.id.settingsButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { SettingsActivity.start(getApplicationContext()); } });`

Comment: I debugged with the breakpoint on startActivity() and it doesn't get there.

Comment: I can't remove the onClick method as it is being used for another functionality, I've updated question with the full method.

Comment: Ok well try adding the on click listener for the settings button in onCreate as I suggested even if you don't remove the implementation on the whole activity.